# Spinning slash wheel to represent an Ongoing operation

Tags: c

I have written a simple program to represent the computer is doing an operation. It is suppose to show a rotating slash character to the user with every second passed however the program does not work as intended. It shows all the characters instead of cleaning the screen and show just the spinning slash character.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
char wheel[3] = {'\\','|','/'};

int j=0;
int i = 0;
while(j<6){
    printf("[%c]",wheel[i]);
    sleep(1);
    system("clear");
    i++;
    if(i>2) i=0;
    j++;
}


return 0;
}
```

Comment: "however the program does not work as intended" That's a problem. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: This question would really fit better on [SO].

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd want to use either `\b` or `\r` to let the new output overwrite the old output without clearing the whole screen.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define elements(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

int main(){
    char wheel[] = {'\\','|','/', '-'};

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
        printf("\r%c", wheel[i%elements(wheel)]);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

`\r` is a carriage return, so it lets you re-print the entire current line of output.
`\b` is a backspace, so it lets you overwrite a single character. In this case, we only have one character on the line, so either on works the same. A backspace would be useful if you wanted to do something on this order:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define elements(x)  (sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]))

int main(){
    char wheel[] = {'\\','|','/', '-'};

    // something written outside the processing loop that needs to be preserved
    printf("Please wait--processing ");

    for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
        // just overwrite the one character for the spinner:
        printf("\b%c", wheel[i%elements(wheel)]);
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Not that it changes much, but OP has the spinner in square brackets.

Comment: Please note, questions involving code that's not working as intended, are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.

Comment: You voted to close the question, yet still answered it. I'm curious. Why?

Comment: @Mast: Stack Overflow (and StackExchange in general) have a reputation for being a bunch of A-holes who care more about enforcing arbitrary rules than actually helping anybody. In particular, demanding that beginners learn lots about the structure of SO/SE, how questions should be asked, etc., before answering questions. This question clearly doesn't fit here so it should be closed. But demanding that the OP jump through (what they see as) flaming hoops to get help is bad too. IMO, the optimal route is to help them, then close the question (and advise them what to do next time).

Answer (score 0):

If you're running windows the command is "CLS" not "clear".
Learning modulo will help you a lot in programming - here you could use `wheel[j%3]` and skip the variable `i`.
Also try to find a way to move the cursor instead of clearing the entire screen.

Comment: No i am using standard librarys (nix*). Good suggestion about the modulo, however i do not know how to remove a character from standard output.

Comment: Please note, questions involving code that's not working as intended, are off-topic on this site. If OP edits their post to address the problem and make their post on-topic, they make your answer moot. [It is advised not to answer such questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6389/120114). Protip: There are tons of on-topic questions to answer; you'll make more reputation faster if you review code in questions that will get higher view counts for being on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that before going to sleep i had to flush the contents of stdout manually and that is why i did get nothing on the screen since printf buffers the output i either have to have a new line character which tells the buffer to flush or use fflush(stdout) before i call the sleep function.

This answer was useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568388/c-sleep-function-not-working

Answer (score 0):

The wheel array is missing the horizontal spoke of the wheel `-`.

The wheel array does not need a number to initialize it.

```
    char wheel[] = {'\\','|','/'};
```

The size of the array can be determined by:

```
    size_t wheel_size = sizeof(wheel) / sizeof(*wheel);
```

Prefer `size_t` over int when indexing arrays. `size_t` is unsigned and can prevent a negative value being used as an index.

The loop can then be written just in terms of the size of the wheel using modulo as suggested by another answer.

```
size_t j=0;
while(j < (2 * wheel_size)){
    printf("[%c]",wheel[j % wheel_size]);
    sleep(1);
    system("clear");
    j++;
}
```